# "unsupported URL" while getting photos from FBSDKGraphRequest

Tags: ios, arrays, facebook, fbsdk

I m trying to fetch photos from Facebook via graph api. When i try this url in Graph api this works but didn't work in my code. I am getting below error:

> Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1002 "unsupported URL"
>   UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=(null)?

And my code is as below

```
let fbRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "227325594139454?fields=photos.limit(10){images}", parameters: nil)
let graphConnection = FBSDKGraphRequestConnection()
                            graphConnection.addRequest(fbRequest, completionHandler: { (connection:FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, result:AnyObject!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
                                if(error != nil){

                                }
                                else
                                {
})
```

Comment: You should pass the fields via `parameters`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite easy url doesn't support "{}" so, just replace html code of "{" and "}" it worked. So "{" will become **%7B** and "}" will become **%7D**.

```
let fbRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "227325594139454?fields=photos.limit(10)%7Bimages%7D", parameters: nil)
```